# AdView attached to bottom doesn't let me see last item in Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-layout, admob, android-recyclerview

I have a `RelativeLayout` in wich I have a `RecyclerView` and a `LinearLayout` with an `AdView` inside. The `RecyclerView` has many items and when I was unable to show them in the screen I just had to scroll down to see them, but now that I added the `LinearLayout` attached to the bottom of the screen with the `AdView` inside I scroll down and I'm not able to see the last item of the `RecyclerView`. I'm attaching the `LinearLayout` to the bottom but it seems that It's above the `RecyclerView` and I want the `RecyclerView` to show items in the screen but not behind the `LinearLayout`. Is it possible?

Here's my XML for the Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rvGeneric"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adViewBaseRefresh"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: For what your doing you may as well change it to LinearLayout, and then set weight for the adView at the bottom

Comment: @Geoff the weight? How do I do that?

Comment: android:layout_weight="0.1"

Comment: And what does it do?

Comment: Add it to that and it'll force it to have minimum space at the bottom

Comment: Give me 1hr and I'll answer this with a working example. I'll be able to get on pc then, on mobile atm.

Comment: Sure, I'll wait. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A relative layout needs "Relative" relationships defined within the XML.  As you don't have any (other than align the linear layout on the bottom), the result is the LL and RecyclerView are overlapping.

Add the line android:layout_below="@id/rvGeneric" to the linear layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ll_ad"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center">

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
             android:id="@+id/adViewBaseRefresh"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="53dp"
             ads:adSize="BANNER"
             ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
             android:layout_marginBottom="3dp">
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvGeneric"
        android:layout_above="@id/ll_ad"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering! I've just tried with that but it didn't work. What else could be wrong?

Comment: Geoff's answer of a LinearLayout is probably simpler... but I also edited mine to work for the RelativeLayout.  The Linearlayout is now defined first, then RecyclerView - RelativeLayout contents can be tricky to get right.

Answer (score 0):

For this I'd personally use a LinearLayout like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.example.geoff.stackoverflowtesting.MainActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rvGeneric"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="TESTING2"
                android:background="#FFF000"
                android:textSize="200dp"
                android:scrollbars="vertical">
            </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/adViewBaseRefresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TESTING"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textColor="#FFF000"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

If you particularly want to use a RelativeLayout then:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.gfaiers.layoutexamples.MainActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rvGeneric"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scrollbars="vertical">
            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adViewBaseRefresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Let me just boot up Android Studio, I'll give them a test and get it for you.  Ugh, got a huge update to do for it... Give me a while.

Comment: Apologies for delay, had to do large update.  I've just tested #1 and it works for me, I've updated the code to show what I've got for it.  As you can see if you run this, the black + yellow testing textview is pinned to the bottom and takes as much space as it needs, giving the rest to the scrollview.  You can still view all the content of what's above as you just need to drag up / scroll down.